# Using NPX command for shell script shebang / interpreter

Tags: node.js, shell, npm, coffeescript, npx

I'd like to run a command line script using the `coffee` executable, but I'd like to call that executable through `npx`.

Something like `#!/usr/bin/env npx coffee` does not work, because only one argument is supported via `env`.

So, is there a way to run an `npx` executable via `env`?

Comment: Commenting as it seems relevant, but doesn't seem to qualify as an answer... According to [this Unix & Linux Stack Exchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/477651), starting with coreutils 8.30 you'll be able to use the `-S` option to pass multiple arguments.

Works on MacOS now with a shebang for TypeScript like:

    `#!/usr/bin/env -S npx ts-node --compiler-options {"module":"commonjs"}`

Unfortunately does not yet work with Debian Buster :(

Comment: My current understanding is that node inserts a "shell"/"cmd" shim whenever it detects a shebang for npx packages. From the cmd shim, it accepts multiple arguments. It's not documented anywhere I know of, but it's in the code: https://github.com/npm/cmd-shim/blob/f59af911f1373239a7537072641d55ff882c3701/index.js#L22

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `ts-node`.

### Any single OS, `ts-node` installed globally

```js
#!/usr/bin/env ts-node

// TypeScript code
```

You probably also need to install `@swc/core` and `@swc/cli` globally unless you do further configuration or tweaking (see the notes at the end). If you have any issues with those, be sure to install the latest versions.

### macOS, `ts-node` not installed globally

```js
#!/usr/bin/env npx ts-node

// TypeScript code
```

Whether this *always* works in macOS is unknown. There *could* be some magic with node [installing a shell command shim](https://github.com/npm/cmd-shim/blob/f59af911f1373239a7537072641d55ff882c3701/index.js#L22) (thanks to @DaMaxContext for commenting about this).

This doesn't work in Linux because Linux distros treat all the characters after `env` as the command, instead of considering spaces as delimiting separate arguments. Or it doesn't work in Linux if the node command shim isn't present (not confirmed that's how it works, but in any case, in my testing, it doesn't work in Linux Docker containers).

This means that `npx ts-node` will be treated as a single executable name that has a space in it, which obviously won't work, as that's not an executable.

*See the notes at the bottom about `npx` slowness.*

### Cross-platform with `ts-node` *not* installed globally in macOS, and some setup in linux

Creating a shebang that will work in both macOS and Linux (or macOS using Docker running a Linux image), without having to globally install `ts-node` and other dependencies in macOS, can be accomplished if one is willing to do a little bit of setup on the Linux/Docker side. Obviously, Linux must have `node` installed.

1. Use the `#!/usr/bin/env npx ts-node` shebang. We just have to fool Linux into thinking that `npx ts-node` with the space is actually a valid executable name.
2. Build a named Docker image that has the required dependencies globally installed and a symbolic link making `npx ts-node` resolve to just `ts-node`.

   Here is an example all-in-one command line on macOS that will both build this image and run it:

   ```bash
   docker buildx build -t node-ts - << EOF
     FROM node:16-alpine
     RUN \
       npm install -g @swc/cli @swc/core ts-node \
       && ln -s /usr/local/bin/ts-node '/usr/local/bin/npx ts-node'
     ENV SWC_BINARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@swc/core/binding
     WORKDIR /app
   EOF

   docker run -it --rm \
     -v "$(pwd):/app" \
     node-ts \
     sh
   ```

   Note that for this example script to work, the above line containing `EOF` must not have any other characters on the line, before or after it, including spaces.
3. Inside of the running container, all `.ts` scripts that have been made executable `chmod +x script.ts` will be executable simply by running them from the command line, e.g., `./test-script.ts`. You can replace the above `sh` with the name of the script, as well (but be sure to precede it with `./` so Docker knows to run it as an executable instead of pass it as an argument to `node`).

## Additional Thoughts & Considerations

There are other ways to achieve the desired functionality.

- The `docker run` command can mount files into the image, including mounting executables in various directories. Some creative use of this could avoid needing to install anything or build a docker image first.
- The install commands could be part of the docker run instead of pre-building an image, but then would be performed on each execution, taking much longer.
- The `PATH` could be modified in macOS, linux, and in the `docker build` to add the folder containing ts-node's `bin.js` from any ts-node `dist` directory, then a shebang of `#!/usr/bin/env bin.js` should theoretically work (and can try `bin-esm.js` to avoid needing SWC, though this enters experimental node territory and may not be suitable for production scripts). This works in macOS, and in Docker outside of an npm project, and in Docker inside of an npm project configured to use TS & swc by passing the `--skipProject` flag to ts-node or setting environment variable `TS_NODE_SKIP_PROJECT=true`. A working test command line example: `docker run -it --rm -v "$(pwd):/app" -e TS_NODE_SKIP_PROJECT=true -w /app --entrypoint sh node:16-alpine -c 'PATH="$PATH:/app/node_modules/ts-node/dist" ./test.ts'`.
- *Any* named executable that can be found in the PATH and run via direct command can be a shebang (using `#!/usr/bin/env executable`). It can be a shell script, a binary file, anything. A shell script can easily be put at a known location, added to the PATH, and then call whatever you like. It could be multi-statement, compiling the file to `.js`, then running that. Whatever your needs are.
- In some special cases you might want to simply use `node` as your shebang executable, setting node options through environment variables to force ts-node as your loader. See [ts-node Recipes:Other](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#other) for more info on this.

Notes:

- The `SWC_BINARY_PATH` [environment variable](https://github.com/swc-project/swc/blob/2bafd53/node-swc/src/index.ts#L17) ensures that ts-node can find the architecture-specific `swc` compiler (to avoid error "Bindings not found"). If you're running on only one architecture, you won't need it. Or, if you are mounting `node_modules` that have these @swc packages already installed for the correct architecture, you won't need it.
- It *is* possible to install node_modules binaries for multiple architectures. The way to do this varies between the different package managers. For example, yarn 3 lets you define which binaries to install all at once in `.yarnrc.yml`. There are other options for npm and possible yarn 1 (and 2?) using environment variables.
- `ts-node` does offer options for running without swc (though this is slower). You could try shebangs with `ts-node-esm` instead of `ts-node`. Look at all the symlinks in the `/usr/local/bin` folder or consult ts-node documentation for more information. If ts-node
- It is possible to run .ts files directly using node and setting node options in environment variables. `node --loader=ts-node` does work, in recent versions (16+?). The experimental mode warnings can be suppressed.
- There are some crazy ways to trick the shell to run JavaScript instead of a unix shell. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63380958/57611) that uses a normal `sh` shebang, but a clever shell statement to transfer execution over to node, that is basically ignored by JavaScript. This isn't great as it requires extra lines of trickery, but could help some people. Other answers on the page are also instructive and it's worth reviewing to get the full picture.
- Some of the complexity here might go away if running `.ts` files *outside* of an npm project. In my own testing in Docker, the context was always in a project having its own `tsconfig.json` and `swc` installed, so with a different setup you might have different results. It proved to be difficult to get `ts-node` to ignore npm project context found with the executed `.ts` file.
- The difference between ESM and CommonJS module handling has not been explained here. This is a complicated topic and beyond the scope of this answer.
- Suffice it to say that if you can figure out how to run your scripts from the command line in the form `executable [options] [file]`, then you should be able to figure out how to run `./[file]` with an appropriate shebang, by mixing and matching all the ideas presented here. You don't have to use ts-node. You can directly use `node`, `swc`, `tsc` itself (by first compiling and then running any .js file or set of .js files in the found context), or any utility or tool that is able to compile or run TypeScript.

Note that using `npx` is significantly slower than running `ts-node` directly, because it may need to download the `ts-node` package, and dependencies, every time it runs.

Some various random tips on possible strategies for SWC architecture support:

- https://socket.dev/npm/package/@rnw-community/nestjs-webpack-swc
- https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2221