# How to disable warnings when node is launched via a (global) shell script

Tags: node.js, npm, fs

I am building a CLI tool with node, and want to use the `fs.promise` API. However, when the app is launched, there's always an `ExperimentalWarning`, which is super annoying and messes up with the interaction prompts. How can I disable this warning/all warnings?

I'm testing this with the latest node v10 lts release on Windows 10.

To use the CLI tool globally, I have added this to my `package.json` file:

```
    { 
      //...
      "preferGlobal": true,
      "bin": { "myapp" : "./index.js" }
      //...
    }
```

And have run `npm link` to link the `./index.js` script. Then I am able to run the app globally simply with `myapp`.

After some research I noticed that there are generally 2 ways to disable the warnings:

1. set environmental variable `NODE_NO_WARNINGS=1`
2. call the script with `node --no-warnings ./index.js`

Although I was able to disable the warnings with the 2 methods above, there seems to be no way to do that while directly running `myapp` command.

The shebang I placed in the entrance script `./index.js` is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node


// my code...
```

I have also read other discussions on modifying the shebang, but haven't found a universal/cross-platform way to do this - to either pass argument to node itself, or set the env variable.

If I publish this npm package, it would be great if there's a way to make sure the warnings of this single package are disabled in advance, instead of having each individual user tweak their environment themselves. Is there any hidden npm `package.json` configs that allow this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I am now using a launcher script to spawn a `child_process` to work around this limitation. Ugly, but it works with `npm link`, global installs and whatnot.

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
const { spawnSync } = require("child_process");
const { resolve } = require("path");

// Say our original entrance script is `app.js`
const cmd = "node --no-warnings " + resolve(__dirname, "app.js");
spawnSync(cmd, { stdio: "inherit", shell: true });
```

As it's kind of like a hack, I won't be using this method next time, and will instead be wrapping the original APIs in a promise manually, sticking to `util.promisify`, or using the blocking/sync version of the APIs.

Answer (score 28):

I configured my test script like this:

```
 "scripts": {
    "test": "tsc && cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules NODE_NO_WARNINGS=1 jest"
  },
```

Notice the `NODE_NO_WARNINGS=1` part. It disables the warnings I was getting from setting `NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules`

**Update**

Consider using [vitest](https://vitest.dev/), the Next Generation Testing Framework. I find it much easier to configure. It's also Jest compatible

Answer (score 11):

New answer: You can also catch emitted warnings in your script and choose which ones to prevent from being logged

```
const originalEmit = process.emit;
process.emit = function (name, data, ...args) {
  if (
    name === `warning` &&
    typeof data === `object` &&
    data.name === `ExperimentalWarning` 
    //if you want to only stop certain messages, test for the message here:
    //&& data.message.includes(`Fetch API`)
  ) {
    return false;
  }
  return originalEmit.apply(process, arguments);
};
```

Inspired by [this patch to yarn](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/blob/2cf0a8fe3e4d4bd7d4d344245d24a85a45d4c5c9/packages/yarnpkg-pnp/sources/loader/applyPatch.ts#L414-L435)

Answer (score 6):

Here's what I'm using to run node with a command line flag:

```
#!/bin/sh
_=0// "exec" "/usr/bin/env" "node" "--experimental-repl-await" "$0" "$@"

// Your normal Javascript here
```

The first line tells the shell to use /bin/sh to run the script. The second line is a bit magical. To the shell it's a variable assignment `_=0//` followed by `"exec" ...`.

Node sees it as a variable assignment followed by a comment - so it's almost a nop apart from the side effect of assigning 0 to _.

The result is that when the shell reaches line 2 it will exec node (via env) with any command line options you need.

Answer (score 6):

I needed to suppress:

> ExperimentalWarning: Importing JSON modules is an experimental feature
> and might change at any time

And this worked for me on Windows, Node.js 18.x:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node --no-warnings
```

After install `--no-warnings` added to `node` calls inside bin scripts `.cmd`,
`.ps`

I guess this won't work for Linux. I didn't manage to find universal solution

Related discussions:

- [Cannot disable warnings when node is launched via a shell script.](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/10802)
- [Node warnings bubble up and in bin scripts can't be disabled](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/32876)
- [Ability to suppress warnings by type (or just experimental warnings)](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/30810)

Answer (score 3):

You can always remove the `warning` listener on your running `process`:

`process.removeAllListeners('warning');`

You might also recreate a listener (`process.on('warning', warning => ...)`) that can catch these warnings and give your process a chance to execute some custom behaviors (maybe ignore some, show others...).